# What tax do I pay when I close a limited company?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, dividends, limited-liability-company

I used to be an IT contractor for many years.
With recent IR35 changes, I have decided to take up a permanent/FTC job.

Over the past year my contract has been under IR35, so I am paying paye tax etc.

I have now decided to close down my limited company.

How will the money that is left in the company be taxed once I take it out post closure? Especially if I want to move the money to a SPV limited company that will handle my BTL property?

Comment: Did you not have an accountant (or established access to one) while you were contracting?